# How to get parameters of a URI deep link into a Maui Application?

Tags: maui, winui

I am want to create a deep link like some-app://localhost?user=123455 that when clicked opens a Maui WinUI app. When the app receives this deep link I want to be able to get the user ID off of the deep link. I was able to do this in Xamarin, but haven't figured out the Maui equivalent

I am able to register the app using (taken from this Windows doc):

```
   <Applications>
    <Application Id= ... >
        <Extensions>
            <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
              <uap:Protocol Name="alsdk">
                <uap:Logo>images\icon.png</uap:Logo>
                <uap:DisplayName>SDK Sample URI Scheme</uap:DisplayName>
              </uap:Protocol>
            </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
      ...
    </Application>
```

But when I receive the event via the app lifecycle (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle#windows) I am not seeing the parameters of the URI.

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: No logs, I just can't find how to get the URI parameters. So when a user prompts my app to open with the URI some-app://localhost?user=123455 . I want to be able to pull the user ID off within the app.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem and I got it working thanks to [this reply](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8855#issuecomment-1190258106) on the issue I created.

*You can retrieve the launch arguments by using Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); inside of OnLaunched.*